# Change Spacy ´s TAG, POS and DEP

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am currently using Spacy to select a sentence and analyse it using the dependency parser. However, I don´t like the DEP, POS and TAG output that it gives me. This is my code :

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy


nlp = spacy.load("es_core_news_sm")

doc = nlp("El perro de Pedro es feo.")

options = {"compact": True, "bg": "#d0caca",
       "color": "black", "font": "Source Sans Pro","arrow_stroke" : 4}


displacy.serve(doc , style = "dep", port = 5500, options = options)
```

Is there any way of changing them without having to train a model? Thanks.

Comment: You don't like the output as in what the model is actually tagging? If that's the case, then yes, you'd have to train a new model